# Use Laravel Mix without ES6 Compilation

Tags: laravel-mix

I'm building something using the Electron framework. I'm using Vue and SCSS, and I'd like to use Laravel Mix.

However, I can't figure out how to use Laravel Mix without ES6 compilation using babel. Since Electron is running on Node, there is no need to compile to ES5.

Looking through Laravel Mix's API, there seems to be no method that provides this functionality.

I created a `.babelrc` file with the following contents:

```
{
    "plugins": [ ],
    "presets": [ ]
}
```

However, after running `npm run dev`, the output file clearly has been transpiled to ES5.

According to [line `248` of `src/config.js`](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/src/config.js#L248) in Laravel Mix's source code, the options taken from `.babelrc` overwrite the default options defined on line `220`.

Laravel Mix Version: `1.7.2`

Is there something I'm missing? Or does Laravel Mix simply not support this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and it wasn't easy to find, but here's the solution:

```
mix.babelConfig({
    only: ["./some-fake-dir"]
})
```

As the Babel documentation says:

> Use it to explicitly enable Babel compilation of files inside the src
>   directory while disabling everything else.

So by entering some fake dir, you turn off the compilation all together.

More on this option here: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#only